# Why is my jQuery slider rendering differently in other browsers as opposed to IE?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, cross-browser

I got my jQuery Slider and Spinners project completed, and when I spoke with my client he sent me a screenshot of the slider in action, but around the handles labels there is an orange border. He is using Chrome and I designed this in IE and there is no orange border around the slider handle's label. 
Is there a reason for this? I have tried adding

```
border:none;
```

to the CSS in the label area but I'm not sure that is going to get rid of the orange box. Is there a way to make sure that there is no orange border? and when it is used in any other browser that it doesn't have an orange border?

Thanks

Comment: @DarrenCrabb, thanks I'll give that a try. I'm going to have to download multiple browsers to see how it looks.

Comment: Just be aware that outline is actually a technology that you shouldn't really mess about with - it's there for the purposes of accessibility, however I know how stupid some clients can be about this sort of stuff and sometimes you just have to go with it. The final look of outline is often decided by whatever browser you use.

Comment: Other things that can be greatly different are file input fields ... safari on Mac is completely different to any other browser (and is quite nice IMHO). It's a good idea to install as many browsers as possible to try stuff on. IE Tester can also save a lot of time for seeing how the IE family of browsers render your page. Ultimately, it's best to check on as many physical different devices as possible too.

Comment: I hear you, clients can be very picky and rightfully so because they pay a lot to have stuff like this done. I have seen code that gets put into the css to deal with other browsers, looks something like this --Mozilla-- but I have no idea where I seen it or if that would even work

Comment: I try to avoid browser specific code if at all possible. Most of the time you can get the page looking how you want without it (it just takes a bit more effort). Some things are only available using browser specific code though. CSS hacks are also best avoided as they generally rely on bugs in the parser that could be fixed in newer versions of the browser.

Comment: I downloaded Chrome and tested in Chrome and FireFox and the orange border is only showing up in Chrome. I see what you're saying about the CSS hacks, you're right the next updates to browsers could mess up the hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple..Well, different browsers render components differently..

For instance, IE and Chrome display 'Alert' messages very differently.

Say, the component might even look different in different versions of the same browser.

It is very difficult, if not impossible, to have ditto UI in all browsers and all versions. As you said, you could play around with CSS to get the same look. But, I have experienced this, a new browser update and everything will be in shambles..

Best Practice.. Throughout the application, in a particular browser, the components should look similar. If it has an orange border in page x, it should have the same in page y too..

Comment: Isn't there some code to put into the css to account for different browsers?

Comment: There definitely is.. navigator.appName gives you the browser engine name.. But my argument is that, it is not the best way to design webpages..

Comment: I have to figure something out because he seems a little put off that there is an orange border around the label.